# Why am I getting Component Exception when using React Native Navigation Drawer

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I am using the Expo Managed React Native.
I am trying to use a drawer navigation and have followed the the React Navigation documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/6.x/drawer-navigator/).

```
import React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen'

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
export default function App() {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

I run the `expo start` command and scan the QR code with my mobile phone.
When running, it throws this error and doesn't run at all. I have tried using a stack navigator and it works fine. Only when using the drawer navigator, the error shows up.

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
 your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `DrawerNavigator`.
```

My dependencies are as follows

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.0.0-next.21",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "expo": "~42.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.11.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.8.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "~0.63.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.14.5",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-native-webview": "11.6.2",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.1.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**i had the same problem, i changed the version > 6... with :**

1 (uninstall)-> *npm uninstall @react-navigation/drawer*

2 -> *npm install @react-navigation/drawer@^5.x*

**that is it!**

Comment: This would mean using a lower version but it will do

Answer (score 0):

check your @react-navigation/drawer with @react-navigation/native